# remove duplicated.values in data.table

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table

I have a following problem. Imagine I have a data.table with a lot of columns and would like to remove duplicated rows based on a vector of column names.

I have a very clumsy solution. Maybe somebody can suggest something better (it should involve data.table as my dataset is rather large):

```
library(data.table)
vec_of_names<-c("x","y")
test<-data.table(x=c(1,1,2,3,4),y=c(1,1,3,4,1),z=c(5,4,3,2,1))
test<-test[,duplicated_key:={paste(.SD,collapse="")},.SDcols=vec_of_names,by=1:nrow(test)]
test<-test[!duplicated(duplicated_key),]
```

Comment: `unique.data.table` has a `by` argument, so `unique(test, by = 1:2)` or `unique(test, by = c('x','y'))` or `unique(test, by = vec_of_names)` should work

Comment: @ Procrastinatus Maximus - thanks a lot I somehow missed the previous answers, very helpful!